# Using apply in dataframe

Tags: r, apply

I am trying to use apply in a dataframe, in order to avoid the for-loops.The code loops over the rows over a dataframe and checks if a cell is equal to its neighbor cell but is not equal to zero.The sum is returned as a new cell:

```
for(i in 1:100){
  same = 0
  for(j in 1:9){
  if(df[i,j]==df[i,j+1] && df[i,j]!=0)
      same = same + 1
  }
 df[i,11] = same
  }
```

How must I treat this?

Comment: What happens when j=10 in your loop? E.g. what is the outcome of df[1,10] == df[1,11] ? I don't think that would work because at that point df[1,11] does not exist unless there is a value in there already. Could you provide some code to create df please?

Comment: Tony you are right. I should write for(j in 1:9).

Answer (score 0):

We can compare the adjacent columns in the dataset by removing the first and last columns, compare whether each of the subset datasets are not equal to 0, get the `rowSums` of the output logical matrix.

```
df1[,11] <- rowSums((df1[-1]==df1[-ncol(df1)]) & 
                    df1[-1]!=0 & df1[-ncol(df1)]!=0 )
```

Using the OP's method, if we calculate the results for the 11th column of 'df'.

```
identical(df1[,11], df[,11])
#[1] TRUE
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:9, 10*100, 
       replace=TRUE), ncol=10))
df <- copy(df1)
```